# The Deployment "my-deployment" is invalid

Tags: kubernetes

I have created a very basic deployment for Kubernetes, but when I try to deploy it

```
$> kubectl apply -f ./hello-world.yaml
The Deployment "my-deployment" is invalid: spec.template.metadata.labels: Invalid value: map[string]string{"app":"bbbb"}: `selector` does not match template `labels`
```

With the following yaml file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-deployment
  labels:
    app: aaaa
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-deployment
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: bbbb
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-deploy
        image: hello-world
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

I have played with the labels and matchLabels a bit, but couldn't fix it. Any suggestions what might be the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, the selector match label in your deployment spec needs to match a label in your template. In your case, you have `app: my-deployment` as a matching label for the selector and you have `app: bbbb` in your template, so no match.

You would have to have something either one `app: my-deployment` or `app: bbbb` on both so that there is a match.